# Multi-Environment Config Database Credentials

Tags: database, server, multi-environment

Being driven to distraction trying to setup multiple environments with Craft. I have Craft running (and working) locally without issue. I have created a staging server with Digital Ocean and setup the appropriate database. I'm using DeployBot to push changes from Github.

However upon trying to access the remote server, I get the following errors:

> Service Unavailable
>
> Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

and

> Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in
>   craft/config/db.php.

I'm sure there is an obvious solution to why this isn't working, but I'm yet to find it.

Here are my db.php and general.php files with sensitive data redacted:

**db.php**

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    'database' => '******',
    'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
  ),

  'localhost' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
  ),

  // Use IP of your droplet and MySQL credentials of a user you created
  '000.000.000.000' => array(
    'server' => '000.000.000.000',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '***********',
  )
);
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

return array(
    '*' => array(
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'devMode' => true,
        'loginPath' => 'users/login',
        'postLoginRedirect' => 'commerce/customer',
        'setPasswordPath' => 'users/setpassword',
        'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
    ),

    '000.000.000.000' => array(
      'siteUrl' => 'http://000.000.000.000/',
      'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => '/var/www/html/',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://000.000.000.000/',
      )
    ),

);
```

**Also index.php file for good measure**

```
<?php

// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../craft';

// Do not edit below this line
$path = rtrim($craftPath, '/').'/app/index.php';

if (!is_file($path))
{
    if (function_exists('http_response_code'))
    {
        http_response_code(503);
    }

    exit('Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that <strong><code>$craftPath</code></strong> is set correctly in '.__FILE__);
}

require_once $path;
```

Help needed and much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what my configuration looks like. Ideally, I'd like to swap out the hard-coded `baseUrl` with something like I have for `basePath`. That way the other members on my team can call/put the site wherever they want and it won't break anything.

I don't make any changes to `index.php`.

Hope this helps!

**db.php**

```
return array(
'*' => array(
    'tablePrefix' => ''
),
'.dev' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'dbname'
),
'mysite.stagingdomain.com' => array(
    'server' => '12.345.67.890',
    'user' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'dbname'
),
'mysite.com' => array(
    'server' => '12.345.67.890',
    'user' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'dbname'
)
```

);

**general.php**

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
    'cpTrigger' => 'admin',  // whatever you want
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'enableCsrfProtection' => true
),
'.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl' => 'http://mysite.dev/',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://mysite.dev/', 
    )
),
'mysite.stagingdomain.com' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl' => 'http://mysite.stagingdomain.com/',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://mysite.stagingdomain.com/'
    )
),
'mysite.com' => array(
    'siteUrl' => 'http://www.mysite.com/',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://www.mysite.com/'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Turns out it was a permissions issue!

Comment: I would think, as long as your site root is at web root (not in a subfolder), you could set `'baseUrl' => '/'` to avoid hard coding the whole URL, yes?

Comment: As obvious as that may seem - I've never tried it but it sure seems like it would work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might find this helpful: [Multi-Environment Config for Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/multi-environment-config-for-craft-cms)